# How can I get a integer value from DLL in VBA?

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I'd like to get the integer value from DLL in VBA as the below code.

```
double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1, BSTR * str, int* str_len)
{
char buff[128] = { 0 };
char * str0;
char str1[128] = { 0 };

int len;


    *dataout0 = *datain0 + 20;
    *dataout1 = *datain1 + 30;
    len = 30;
    *str_len = 30;

    str0 = " Nice ";
    sprintf(buff, "Hi  %s  \n", str0);
    strcpy(str1, buff);

    char* p = str1;
    SysReAllocString(str, (OLECHAR*)p);

    return 0;
}
```

VB

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function pll_dll Lib "F:\work\pll_dll\x64\Debug\pll_dll.dll" _
(ByRef x_in As Double, ByRef y_in As Double, ByRef x_out As Double, ByRef y_out As Double, ByRef s As String, ByRef str_len As Integer) As Double

Dim s_len As Integer
Call pll_dll(3, 4, d1, d2, s, s_len)
```

But I can't understand, when I ran above code, s_len is always '0'at the vba .
but the other parameter double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1, BSTR * str are all working good.

the funny things, when I get rid of " BSTR * str," parameter from
when I ran with "    double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1, int* str_len)" then I can get the str_len as well

can you let me know what should I have to check ?
How can I get the s_len value?

Answer (score 3):

**You are misusing `SysReAllocString()`.**

You are giving it an 8-bit ANSI string that is merely typecasted to a 16-bit pointer.  It expects a proper 16-bit Unicode string instead.  If you get rid of the typecast, the code would fail to compile, and for good reason.  Don't use typecasts to avoid compiler errors.

You must convert your output string data to Unicode before you can then create a `BSTR` for it.

You need to either:

- use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert your final `char` data to `wchar_t`.

  ```
  double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1, BSTR * str, int* str_len)
  {
      char c_buff[128] = {0};
      wchar_t w_buff[128] = {0};
      char * str0;
      int len;

      *dataout0 = *datain0 + 20;
      *dataout1 = *datain1 + 30;

      len = 30;
      *str_len = len;

      str0 = " Nice ";
      len = sprintf(c_buff, "Hi %s \n", str0);

      len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, c_buff, len, w_buff, 128);

      SysReAllocStringLen(str, w_buff, len);

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- rewrite the code to use `swprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.

  ```
  double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1, BSTR * str, int* str_len)
  {
      wchar_t buff[128] = {0};
      wchar_t * str0;
      int len;

      *dataout0 = *datain0 + 20;
      *dataout1 = *datain1 + 30;

      len = 30;
      *str_len = len;

      str0 = L" Nice ";
      len = swprintf(buff, L"Hi %s \n", str0);

      SysReAllocStringLen(str, buff, len);

      return 0;
  }
  ```